# How to move SDK file after android studio is installed

Tags: android-studio

I am not able to move SDK file after the android studio is installed. Can you guide me step by step.

Comment: Which file? The whole SDK folder?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. OPEN android studio first
2. open SDK manager in android studio
3. change the LOCATION OF sdk where you save sdk.

Answer (score 24):

To actually MOVE an existing Android Studio SDK folder location in Windows:

1. Close Android studio.
2. In windows File Explorer, MOVE the actual SDK folder.
3. For example, my SDK folder was located here
   C:\Users\bfindling\AppData\Local\Android\sdk so I cut/pasted it to
       E:\Android\sdk
4. Now you can re-launch Android Studio and it will notice that the SDK
   has moved.
5. It will ask you for the new location.
6. Point it to the new location (for example E:\Android\sdk) and you are done.

Comment: you can also use flutter command line, for example ```flutter config --android-sdk D:\Android\Sdk```

Answer (score 8):

1. Open android studio
2. Go to File in menu bar
3. Select settings
4. Click on Appearance & Behavior on Settings window
5. Go to System Settings
6. Then Android SDK
7. And there you will find Android SDK Location
8. Change the path to where your sdk files are located

[Android SDK location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaadA.png)

Comment: my android studio path is different than sdk location. will there be any problem for that? if yes then what is the solution.

Comment: The path should point to your current sdk location. If it is not then click edit button on right of path textbox and point it to right folder.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter defaults to look for the SDK inside of the Android Studio directory.
This causes a conflict: And you must update flutter to look for the SDK where it is installed or move the SDK to a location outside of the Android Studio directory and point flutter to that location otherwise Android Studio will NOT allow you to use it while it reside within its directory.

I just did a fresh install. Then move the SDK to the lib directory where flutter was  expecting it to be.

I just followed other answers from this forum, and nobody mentions this. But yet I am banned.

I will file a bug report in flutter git.