# Unable to run emulator using latest cmdline-tools cli

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-sdk-manager

Unable to run emulator using the cmdline-tools, im getting the following error

```
root@8110fcf520fc:~# emulator -avd pixel -verbose -no-boot-anim -no-window -gpu off -accel off
emulator: Android emulator version 30.7.5.0 (build_id 7491168) (CL:N/A)
emulator: Found AVD name 'pixel'
emulator: Found AVD target architecture: x86
emulator: argv[0]: 'emulator'; program directory: '/opt/Android/Sdk/emulator'
emulator:  Not a directory: /opt/Android/Sdk/Sdk/system-images/android-30/google_apis_playstore/x86/

PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value [/opt/Android/Sdk]!
root@8110fcf520fc:~# emulator -avd pixel -verbose -no-boot-anim -no-window -gpu off -accel off
```

all global variables are configured, I'm just curious why it shows the following error

```
emulator:  Not a directory: /opt/Android/Sdk/Sdk/system-images/android-30/google_apis_playstore/x86/
```

however system-imges is installed properly inside the ANDROID_SDK_ROOT directory

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. My user path contains a non ASCII char. Try this:

**Move .android and SDK folder and reset configs**

1. close all editors and all android related programs;
2. check the location of the ".android" folder;
3. create a new folder under a path which is highly compatible to faulty implementations (no-spaces, less 255 characters length, only ascii-characters [I put it in C:\Android and I moved also SDK folder into it.])
4. move the .android-folder into the previously created folder;
5. open the avd-subfolder of the .android-folder;
6. open each ".ini"-file (each corresponding an emulator stored in a directory with the same name without the .ini-extension);
7. replace the old path in the value of the path-property in each file by the new path of the .android-folder so that it points emulator-directory;
8. open the windows environment variable settings dialog;
9. add a new entry or edit the existing one for ANDROID_SDK_HOME (for me: C:\Android);
10. set the value to the location of the folder which contains the .android-folder. (not the .android-folder itself [for me: C:\Android]);
11. Move SDK content as specified here: [How to move SDK file after android studio is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39053423/how-to-move-sdk-file-after-android-studio-is-installed/39053906;)

**Confirm the solution is working in Visual Studio Code:**

1. start the editor;
2. check if the emulators are listed in the device list (down-right blue button).

If you move folders like I did, you will have in windows environment variable I have:

1. ANDROID_HOME = C:\Android\Sdk ;
2. ANDROID_SDK_HOME = C:\Android ;
3. ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = C:\Android\Sdk;

Solution inspired from some answers here:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/panic-cannot-find-avd-system-path-please-define-an/1005744

Maybe not, but I hope it can be useful anyway